# Posting Multipart and string content web API using Ajax in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have multipart content web API. which is working fine.and tested in postman.
Now i am trying to consume that web api in my asp.net web application using ajax post method. I referred some coding in google and applied. but it shows error finally. i don't know what's the misake i am doing.  I am using .Net Framework 4.5.  My coding and postman execution of my api as Below .

```
                var data = new FormData();
                jQuery.each(jQuery('#fileupload')[0].files, function (i, file) {
                    data.append('file', file);
                });

                data.append('siteCode', 'HQ');
                data.append('phoneNumber', '95878784XXX');
                data.append('customerCode', 'C001');
                data.append('notificationFlag', '1');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: SequoiaUri + "api/profilePicture",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    Cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Picture Uploaded Successfully!");
                    }
```

[image]

Can anyone help me what's the error in my ajax post method...

Comment: Can you please share your controller's action method?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: SequoiaUri + "/api/profilePicture",
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    //enctype: 'multipart/form-data',  // try if still is not working
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
   success: function (data) {
   alert("Picture Uploaded Successfully!");
                    },
.....
```